# How to "invert" numbers in Java

Tags: java

Lets say I have a number 1-5, now if I have 2, I want 4 as an output, if I had 3 then have 3 as the output, if I have 1 then 4 as the output. Here is a chart of what I want:

1-10 Chart:

```
Give 1 return 9
Give 2 return 8
Give 3 return 7
Give 4 return 6
Give 5 return 5
```

What algorithm do I use for such a thing?

Comment: If I understood what you're saying correctly, you want to print the number that is equidistant away from the end as the input number is from the start? That's basically the length - your number.

Comment: ' 1-5, now if I have 2, I want 4...' is this example right?

Comment: Joe and IHawk, yes that's exactly it.

Comment: it's not difficult if you have a collection or array, then only what you have to do is substraction length and actual position

Answer (score 2):

I don't see that you need an algorithm as much. What you have is:

```
InverseNumber = (myCollection.Length - MySelection);
```

Thats all you need for even numbers.

With a collection of 1 - 6 for example:
 Give 2; 6 - 2 = 4. Also if given 4, 6 - 4 = 2.

You will need a slightly different problem for odds:

1 - 5; with 1 given 1 is at index 0, the opposite is 5, 2 given and the inverse ( 5 - 2) is 3. But if 3 is given, there is no inverse. So you might want to also add a catch for:

```
if (((myCollection.Length *.5).Round) == mySelection) { //Inverse does not exist!!!}
```

If you are using just integers, and not arrays of numbers then just replace the myCollection.Length with the upperbound integer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following code will work for what you need:

```
int a[] = new a[length_needed];
int counter = length_needed;
for(int c = 0; c < length_needed; c++) {
   a[c] = counter;
   counter--;
}
int number_inputed;
for(int c = 0; c < length needed; c++) {
   if(c == number_inputed) System.out.println(a[c]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are giving max number as input. Then you are going to have `0-n` numbers. For ex., if 9 is the max number you will have `0-9`.

Then you can do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] a) {
   int max = a[0]; // read values from cmd line args

   int forWhichNum = a[1]; //for which number we need its inverse

   Sop(max- forWhichNum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer value = 2;
Integer maxValue = 6;
Integer reverseCounter = 0;
for (int i = maxValue; i > 0; i--) {
    reverseCounter++;
    if (i == value) {
        return reverseCounter;
    }
}
```